# Override Equals for indexOf in Arrylist

Tags: java, overriding

```
import java.util.*; 

public class CustomList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public boolean equals(Object b) {
        if (b instanceof Node) {
            Node other = (Node) b; 
            return this.getKey().equals(other.getKey());
        }

        return false; 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the indexOf of my cumstomList, so I want to override equals method, so that it will compare only the key for me.

But, the above code generates error says "this.getKey" cannot find symbol
So, im wondering what should I put to return if i want to compare the Node's key ?

Another quesion, why I can't put "Node" in the CustomList "E" and ArrayList "E" ?

=====
I mean, if i have a arrayList of type Node, and I want to get the indexOf a Node by it's key, can i override equals, so that the indexOf only compare the key for me , is it possible ?

Comment: You don't have getKey() defined in your CustomList class. ArrayList in Java does not have getKey() so you aren't inheriting it. Perhaps you are looking for the Map class?

Comment: I also want the index of a key.. so I think Map wont works, but thanks!

Comment: If you tell us what you are trying to do with your custom data structure, we can help point you to a class that most likely exists already. If you have the key, I don't see why you would want to find its index unless you want an ordered Map https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Comment: You are confused. The `indexOf()` method of the `List` uses the `equals()` method of the **elements**, not the `equals()` method of the `List`. If you want the `List.indexOf()` method to lookup by only certain key fields of the element, change the `E.equals()` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Equals method in your custom list should take instance of list as argument and not Node type. This you have to do in your Node class equals method.

Comment: Nah.. not correct, indexOf seems is not using equals of node to find the index of the node

Comment: As mentioned by @Andreas in one of the comment the indexOf method of ArrayList use the equals method of Element and not the list. Here is the url to code of ArrayList indexOf method: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare values in Node, the correct implementation is something like this for a Node class:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

If you want each Node connected to other Nodes, you can keep as attribute for each Node the following Objects:

```
private T val;
private ArrayList<Node<T>> children;
```

If you need to traverse the connected Nodes, you can a separate class to keep track of the head Node and implement it as an iterator:

```
class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<Node> {
    private Node<T> rootNode;
    private int numNodes;
}
```

Then, you will be able to use the Tree class to easily iterate through your Nodes to find the position of the Node you are looking for.